# Area bounded under curves

Tags: calculus

Question says:
By changing to polar coordinates,find the area bounded by the curves $x^2$+$y^2$=$2y$
,$x^2$+$y^2$=$4y$
,$x=y$ and $x=0$.

Comment: So what did u try?

Comment: Net that you have two circle equations $ x^2+y^2 = 2y \iff  x^2+(y-1)^2=1^2$ and $ x^2+y^2 = 4y \iff  x^2+(y-2)^2=2^2$.

Comment: @AlexanderVigodner I tried to make the intersection of two circle one with centre 1 and the other with centre 2.also a common intersection with a line $x=y$. And then tried to get limits IN TERMS OF POLAR COORDINATES

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In polar coordinate $x^2+y^2=r^2$, $x=r\cos{\theta}$, $y=r\sin{\theta}$ all your curves
will be rewritten as follows:
$$
r=2\sin{\theta}\\
r=4\sin{\theta}\\
\theta=\pi/4;\\
\theta=\pi/2
$$
I believe it is not a problem now to calculate an integral $\int rdrd\theta$ over 
$$
\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2} d\theta \int_{2\sin{\theta}}^{4\sin{\theta}}rdr
$$